# Get GeoJSON data from AJAX enabled service

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I want to get GeoJSON data from GeoServer using asp.net and AJAX enabled service. firstly I made a class for request web:

```
public class Request
{
    public static string WebRequestByUrl(string url)
    {
        string jsonData = "";
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                jsonData = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace("'", "-");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
        return jsonData;
    }
}
```

and AJAX enabled service codes

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Mapping
{
    // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
    // To create an operation that returns XML,
    //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
    //     and include the following line in the operation body:
    //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
    [OperationContract]
    public string WebRequestByUrl(string url)
    {
        // Add your operation implementation here
        return Request.WebRequestByUrl(url);
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
```

and JavaScript side

```
var mapping = {
getTmJson : function () {
    var url = "http://10.212.81.15:8080/geoserver/BEIS_WS/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=BEIS_WS:ilce&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json";
    var service = new Mapping();
    service.WebRequestByUrl(url, function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        mapping.showData(data);
    }, null, null);
},
showData: function (data) {
    var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.MapQuest({
            layer: 'sat'
        })
    });

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
            projection: 'EPSG:5254',
            object:data
        })
    });

    var select = new ol.interaction.Select();

    var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
        features: select.getFeatures()
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, modify]),
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: 'osm' }) }), vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });
}
```

}

and result I can get JSON data from GeoServer, but I can't make it integrate with OpenLayers vector

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
            projection: 'EPSG:5254',
            **object:data**
        })
    });
```

error is
`** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined**`

where is my mistake?

Comment: Try to readout your JSON response in a file or webpage and then see if ti's proper JSon on : http://jsonlint.com/ 
If it's proper JSON your error is on the client side if not it's on the server side.

Comment: well i have done it. i can show geojson wfs data from geoserver and edit with interactions on map but i dont know how to record transactions to geoserver ?